# How to append some extra text in the div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to take the label text of the checkbox which are checked and I trying to append in the span tag,

When user click the the ok button in the popUp
Here it is not working. Here is my **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVeVd/1/)**

My script is:

```
$('.modal-footer .preSuccess').click(function(){            
            var parentElement=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            $('#'+parentElement+ '.modal-body  input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                var pre =$(this).next('label').text();
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    $('.'+parentElement+'Pre').append('<span>'+pre+'</span>'); 
                }   
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.modal-footer .preSuccess').click(function () {
    var modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
    var parentElement = modal.attr('id'); // issue here, use closest to get a parent matching the selector
    //again issue with the selector
    modal.find('.modal-body  input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        var pre = $(this).next('label').text();
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.' + parentElement + 'Pre').append('<span>' + pre + '</span>');
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EEvc5/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny In the answer if I select the option [Any] its not reading the label of Any can you please check it http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EEvc5/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you check it please

Comment: @SureshPattu there is another problem in the `Any` checkbox, between the checkbox and the label there is a hidden field, move it to after the label

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code and you're missing a space when querying the checkbox:

```
 $('#'+parentElement+ ' .modal-body  input[type="checkbox"]')
```

It wasn't able to find your checkbox and couldn't find the texts.

Other than that I would advice against the .parent().parent() structure, cause it's very prone to future bugs. Maybe just call the id directly, but I'm not sure how you're using this code.